# Reading dll.config (not app.config!) from a plugin module

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, settings, appsettings

I am writing a C# .NET 2.0 .dll that is a plug in to a [Larger application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD).  The visual studio project for my module has a app.config file which is copied to a MyProj.dll.config along side of MyProj.dll.

The plan is that MyProj.dll.config will be edited after the .dll is deployed.  I am trying to read my settings from that modified local file.  I have tried pulling out the LocalFilesSettingsObject and changing it's application name to my .dll like this:

```
        Properties.Settings config = Properties.Settings.Default;
        SettingsContext context = config.Context;
        SettingsPropertyCollection properties = config.Properties;
        SettingsProviderCollection providers = config.Providers;
        SettingsProvider configFile = Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"];
        configFile.ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        config.Initialize(context, properties, providers);
        config.Reload();
```

That is not working.  I am struggling to wrap my head around the whole .NET Settings mess.  I'd like a recipe to finish this task.  I would also like a link to a clear explanation (with examples) of how settings are supposed to work in .NET 2.0

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will need to load the `x.dll.config` (with the Configuration API) yourself. All the automatic file handling (including the `.Settings`) is all about machine.config/y.exe.config/user-settings.

To open a named config file:

- Reference `System.Configuration.dll` assembly.
- Using `System.Configuration`
- Create code like:

  ```
  Configuration GetDllConfiguration(Assembly targetAsm) {
    var configFile = targetAsm.Location + ".config";
    var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap {
      ExeConfigFilename = configFile
    };
    return ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
  }
  ```

Comment: curly braces are placed on where they're supposed to be. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 7):

**1- open app.config file in visual studio**

**2- in the "configuration" tag add your configurations in tag "appSettings" as bellow:**

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="UserName" value="aaa"/>
        <add key="Password" value="111"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**3- in your code c#**

```
var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string userName = appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["UserName"].Value;
string password = appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["Password"].Value;
```

and do not forgot to add this 2 usings for "ConfigurationManager" and for "Assembly"

- using System.Configuration;
- using System.Reflection;

if the System.Configuration does not show, you must add the reference "System.Configuration" in the References

**4- you can update the configurations for the dll as bellow:**

- open the file "**MyProj.dll.config**"
- then update your configurations

Comment: Thanks Mohamad! I read through many of these posts and yours is the only one that worked!