# C# how to access config file from another PC over the network

Tags: c#, networking, server, settings, config

I want to **Access** configuration file from another computer example.

```
string location = @"\\SERVER\Shared\Ramgy\Settings.config"

// get server from **SERVER** location
this.txthostname.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.server; 

// get port from the SERVER location
this.txtport.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.port; 

//get username from the SERVER location
this.txtusername.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.username;

// get password from the SERVER location
this.txtpassword.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.password;

// get database from the SERVER location
this.txtdatabase.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.database;
```

Comment: You'll have to read it using a UNC network path.

Comment: @JeremyThompson can you give us some example of UNC network.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I got an answer to my question I'd used `string server = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Hostname").InnerText;` to get the server.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Ive used **XmlDocument** not **UNC**

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as correct, my link to the Linq XML method worked? Yes. It will give you a few points and let everyone know problem is solved

Comment: @JeremyThompson Yes definitely correct, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Reading a Dlls own config:
var executingAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var location = executingAssembly.Location; //C:\MyApp\bin\Debug\Search.dll

//Read a colleagues config file (the settings.settings are stored in config):
location = "\\JoeBlogsPC\c$\AppPath\Search.dll";

var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(location);
var sections = config.Sections;
string s = config.AppSettings.Settings["Something"].Value.ToString();
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15726277/495455
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9763947/495455

---

If you get stuck with `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` try System.Xml.Linq instead

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939187/495455

---

Another way to load a specific exe configuration file:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "EXECONFIG_PATH" };
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587078/495455

Comment: all I want is to access this connection `string location = @"\\SERVER\Shared\Ramgy\Settings.config";` and extract server,port, username etc. thanks

Comment: `string s = config.AppSettings.Settings["Something"].Value.ToString();` Object reference not set to an instance of an object.