# loading dll config file when it is referenced in web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, dll

I have created a WCF web service which has references to some class library (BO.dll,BLL.dll,DAL.dll) ,and invoke their methods . one of the libraries(DAL.dll) need a config file to read some settings like connection string . then the config file is located near to the dll files .
but when I use the service, it has error which the "could not find file C:\windows\microsoft.NET\FrameWork\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\SampleService(some temp folder)\myConfigFile.config"

I should say that, dll code read the config file as a simple xml file. and extract the settings.

why it looks for in this address ?
where should I put the config file to be accessible by the dll ?

Comment: Try to put the connection string in your webconfig

Comment: there are more settings in config file. I need a separate file for dll configs.

Comment: try to add all of them. i am not sure but it may br the solution .

Comment: I will do !if i can not find another solution!

Comment: I hope this can help you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juBDM3fb-i0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because for DLL you need to use your webservice's configuration file for DLL if you are reading connection string using 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManger.AppConfig class.

Otherwise you can reading manually.

This link might help you

[Reading dll.config (not app.config!) from a plugin module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208793/reading-dll-config-not-app-config-from-a-plugin-module)

Comment: dll read the config file as a simple xml file. and extract the settings.