# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"] not returning any value

Tags: c#, .net

In my `app.config` I have added a key with value

```
<add key="KeyName" value="someValue" />
```

But in my windows form when i try to access it by using configurationmanager it is not returning anything

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"]
```

this has null value
Also i dont have any web.config or connection string added in the app.config, but my 
`ConfigurationManager.connectionString` returns some value !!

What might be the issue? what should i change?

P.S
I have added reference to `system.configuration` and added it in namespace too
its an excel add-in and has only one class library which has app.config

Comment: Is this part of a website, and the `app.config` file you are trying to access is part of a project that's added to this solution

Comment: No its an excel add-in and has only one class library which has app.config

Comment: Let's say you have a DLL project. And you added app.config to this DLL project. Let's say you have a windows service project that uses the DLL project. If you are trying to read app.config in your DLL project via the windows service, it would look for the windows service project root for the app.config since the application started from there. Try adding your config entries to the app.config which is executed first. The windows service, in my example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put all configurations you use is in the app.config file that belongs to the host application (the one that produce the executable file). 
If you put configuration in dll configuration file they will not be automatically picked up in the run time, and you will have to dynamically load those configuration using code similar to the one in this post. Not sure if this is your issue.
[Reading dll.config (not app.config!) from a plugin module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208793/reading-dll-config-not-app-config-from-a-plugin-module)
As for where the connection is coming from, it is coming from the machine configuration file 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64[version]\config\machine.config

If you have SQL Server including express installed a connection string will be added to this file

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your application is returning other AppSetting Values ?

static void ReadAllSettings()
        {
            try
            {
                var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

```
            if (appSettings.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("AppSettings is empty.");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var key in appSettings.AllKeys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, appSettings[key]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error reading app settings");
        }
    }
```

Comment: i only have one key and one value inside it and its not reading that